# How can I detect a program that is not responding and restart it?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a program - iCue - that occasionally crashes so I'm taking matters into my own hands and creating a program to restart iCue whenever it becomes unresponsive. Only problem is: iCue doesn't exactly become unresponsive, it just responds to input very slowly.

Here is my code so far:

```
@echo off 
taskkill /im "iCue" /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" /f >nul && start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Corsair\CORSAIR iCUE Software\iCue.exe"
```

Does anybody know how to "ping" the program and check the delay of response, and then restart it?

Comment: If you're going to want more complexity you might have to dig into the Windows API and try sending `WM_NULL` messages to a window and recording time deltas in the callback to determine how _responsive_ the program is.

Comment: I doubt that using `TaskKill`, filtering for a not responding program, would identify a program which responds, _just slowly_! You're supposed to code to perform the task based on your own research, not code something which definitely doesn't perform the task, and ask what does.

Comment: "I have a program - iCue - that occasionally crashes" - fix the actual problem!